# How enable zoom for second y axis in charts JS

Tags: javascript, chart.js, graph-visualization

I have 2 Y axis in my graph and both of needs to be zoomed on scroll.Chart plugin () provides options - x,y,xy.Here, xy zooms only first y axis not not the second.

```
    {
// Container for pan options
pan: {
    // Boolean to enable panning
    enabled: true,

    // Panning directions. Remove the appropriate direction to disable 
    // Eg. 'y' would only allow panning in the y direction
    mode: 'xy'
},

// Container for zoom options
zoom: {
    // Boolean to enable zooming
    enabled: true,

    // Zooming directions. Remove the appropriate direction to disable 
    // Eg. 'y' would only allow zooming in the y direction
    mode: 'xy',
}
```

}

Comment: Can you add your chart.js config to your question to get an example for how you have your scales configured?

Comment: Unfortunately, per the [source](https://github.com/chartjs/chartjs-plugin-zoom/blob/master/src/chart.zoom.js#L318), the zoom plugin uses the first y scale in your chart if you have more than one.  You could try opening an issue in github to request multiple y axis support.